# How to (De)serialize mock of an interface?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, serialization, mocking, moq

I'm testing a method that takes quite long interface as an argument (25 properties), and since that interface has several implementations I want to mock it instead of using actual object.

Some of these properties contain strings of over 6000 characters, so keeping this data in code is out of question. In cases like this I keep data in embedded resources, and here starts my problem.

Here is sample interface:

```
public interface IComplexInterface
{
    string Content { get; set; }

    string Description { get; set; }

    string Title { get; set; }

    /* a lot more */
}
```

I tried to first serialize my hard-coded mock into JSON to know what structure will it take, so I can store it:

```
var mock = new Mock<IComplexInterface>();

mock.SetupGet(x => x.Content).Returns("around 6000-9000 characters");
mock.SetupGet(x => x.Description).Returns("another 2000 characters");
mock.SetupGet(x => x.Title).Returns("just few characters");
/* and so on */

var serializedMock_1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mock);        // Mock<IComplexInterface>
var serializedMock_2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mock.Object); // IComplexInterface
```

Sadly, I when I try to deserialize any of these, I get:

with `Mock<IComplexInterface>`:
`'ISerializable type 'Castle.Proxies.IComplexInterface' does not have a valid constructor. To correctly implement ISerializable a constructor that takes SerializationInfo and StreamingContext parameters should be present. Path 'Object', line 1, position 1022.`

with `IComplexInterface`:
`'Could not create an instance of type MyApp.IComplexInterface. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path '__interceptors', line 1, position 18.'`

Is there any way I can do it, so I can store this mocks in resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating your own mock class instead of a `Mock<your interface>`. I.e. a class implementing the interface, which is used for test purposes only. It could load its contents from an embedded resource or a file.

Comment: Well, I guess that will have to do for now, though I'm still looking for a way to do it with Mock, so I can use `Verify()`, `VerifyGet()` and so on.